# Is there a strictly increasing family $\{ f_\alpha:\alpha<\aleph_1 \} \subseteq \omega^\omega$ of size $<\aleph_1$

Tags: set-theory

Is there a strictly increasing family $\{  f_\alpha:\alpha<\aleph_1 \} \subseteq \omega^\omega$   of size $<\aleph_1$ such that

1. $f_\alpha\leq^* f_\beta$ if $\alpha\leq\beta<\aleph_1$
2. $\lim_{n\to \infty}(f_\alpha(n)-f_{\alpha}(n-1))=\infty$
3. $f_\alpha(n)\leq f_{\alpha+1}(n-1)$ for all except finitely many $n$ ?

How I can build this family?  Any suggestions.

Comment: I think that in this case you should specify that $\omega^\omega $ the set of functions $\omega\to\omega $ (or use $\Bbb N $ instead of $\omega $) because $\omega^\omega $ might be confused with the *ordinal* $\bigcup\limits_{\alpha\in\omega} \omega^\alpha $.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: It’s clear enough in context, though I do prefer to use ${^\omega\omega}$ for the set of functions.

Comment: Wait, do you really mean "of size $<\aleph_1$"? I think you mean "of size $=\aleph_1$" . . . (especially since you've written "$\{f_\alpha: \alpha<\aleph_1\}$", which implies the family has size $=\aleph_1$).

Comment: @brian It took me a couple of minutes, but I understood it. I was just suggesting a way to save others my same trouble. Of course, my comment can be sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

Let's look first of all at your condition (1) by itself. We can easily construct such a family, via the following fact:

> $(*)\quad$ If $\mathcal{C}$ is a countable collection of functions $\omega\rightarrow\omega$, then there is an $f$ which is $\ge^*$ every element of $\mathcal{C}$.

*Proof*. List $\mathcal{C}$ as $g_0, g_1, g_2, g_3, . . .$, and let $f(n)=1+\sum_{k\le n}g_k(n)$.  $\quad\Box$

This lets us construct a $\le^*$-increasing $\omega_1$-sequence of functions, via transfinite induction. (Of course we need a small amount of AC here.)

Specifically, the proof of $(*)$ gives us a *template* for producing such sequences, as long as we have a mechanism for picking bijections between countable ordinals and $\omega$: fix some "initial" $\omega$-sequence $f_0, f_1, f_2, . . .$ with the appropriate properties, and then - for $\alpha\ge\omega$ a countable ordinal, and $b_\alpha:\alpha\rightarrow\omega$ the picked bijection between $\alpha$ and $\omega$ - let $f_\alpha$ be the function produced via $(*)$ applied to the collection $\{g_{\alpha,i}: i\in\omega\}$, where $g_{\alpha, i}=f_{b_\alpha^{-1}(i)}$.

Now, what if you want your sequence to have other properties - such as your (2) and (3)? Well, just alter the template $(*)$ appropriately! Rather than the specific choice of $f$ used in the proof of $(*)$ given above, pick a different expression for $f$ which grows "fast enough" (in the relevant ways) to satisfy your requirements.

For instance, we can get condition (2) to hold by replacing the definition of $f$ in $(*)$ with $$f(n)=n^2+\sum_{k\le n}g_k(n).$$

Similarly, for condition (3) we want $f(n)>g_i(n+1)$ for all but finitely many $n$s. We can achieve this by just adding more terms to the sum in the definition of $f$; e.g. $$f(n)=n^2+\sum_{k\le n}\left(\sum_{j\le n+2}g_k(j)\right)$$ folds in both (2) and (3) simultaneously. (Actually, a statement stronger than (3) is satisfied here.)

---

Note that this general method **cannot** be modified to work for sequences of length $>\omega_1$, since to form the $\omega_1$st term of such a sequence we would need to "meet $\omega_1$-many requirements" simultaneously, and we really only know how to meet countably many requirements at once. The existence of such sequences, in fact, is independent of ZFC; **Martin's axiom** (plus the negation of the Continuum Hypothesis) tends to be the right additional axiom needed to construct them.